# Connecting to home server without port forwarding

Tags: ssh, vpn, home-server, internet-security, nordvpn

I would like repurposed an old laptop of mine into a **home linux SSH server**, to be able to access all my files from my phone over the internet by using Termux to establish the SSH connection.

Problem is my wanna be SSH server laptop sits behind an home router without a static IP address. Furthermore my home network is populated by not so technically inclined people (*id est:* my family) and so home network security should be rock solid.

For this reasons I don't like the idea to perform a port forwarding in my home router: I don't want security risks, and also I don't want my network slowed down by bots trying to break in my forwarded SSH port.

**So my question is:** is there another way to remotely connect to my machine at home? Without forwarding a port directly?

I heard something can be done by using a VPN service, and I am willing to pay a monthly fee for this, but I have really no idea how it would be possible to use a VPN service (like Nord VPN) to remotely connect to my home network or directly into my SSH server.

Comment: if u don't mind commercial company, maybe check [tailscale](https://tailscale.com/)? and there have a oss version server side [headscale](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/headscale) if u want run your own server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> For this reasons I don't like the idea to perform a port forwarding in my home router: I don't want security risks, and also I don't want my network slowed down by bots trying to break in my forwarded SSH port.

Security risks come from the service itself, not from port forwarding in general. That is, bots can *only* keep attacking your SSH service but they cannot "go around it" into the rest of your network.

(And, regular bot traffic is usually a few hundred of connections per day – *not* per minute – so it's still in the kB/s range in average. If the uplink of your home network can't handle it, then it won't be able to handle your file transfers either.)

> I heard something can be done by using a VPN service, and I am willing to pay a monthly fee for this, but I have really no idea how it would be possible to use a VPN service (like Nord VPN) to remotely connect to my home network or directly into my SSH server.

If you're talking about commercial, privacy-oriented VPN services – yes, this is sometimes an extra feature that you can request. Normally such VPN services block incoming connections completely and change your assigned address often, but with some providers you can request either the same kind of "port forward" (a single port on a static addresses being routed to your VPN client machine) or a whole dedicated IP address for the VPN client. As long as your home server remains connected to the VPN, it'll be able to receive inbound connections over that tunnel.

(NordVPN [does not offer this](https://support.nordvpn.com/FAQ/1047408432/Do-you-offer-port-forwarding.htm), although the explanation they give doesn't quite work.)

But to be clear, if you want the service to be accessible from anywhere (i.e. without a special client, just `ssh <ip>`) then it will indeed be accessible from anywhere *regardless of a VPN being involved* – if you can connect to the address issued by the VPN provider, so can bots. Such a VPN service will happily forward the bruteforce attempts to your homeserver.

What would be useful here is a *slightly different* kind of VPN service – one where both the home server **and** the roaming client can connect to the same VPN and be part of their own isolated network. This can be either a self-hosted VPN (such as an instance of OpenVPN or WireGuard running on a *non*-home VPS that has a public IP address), or a semi-centralized service (such as Tailscale or ZeroTier). The downside is that you *must* connect to the VPN in order to reach your home network.

(Security-wise, you still have to expose one service (the VPN server) to the outside world, but compared to exposing SSH you have slightly more flexibility in regards to how the service responds to unauthenticated connections; e.g. a WireGuard server (or OpenVPN with HMAC key) won't even respond to the first packet, which is less resource-intensive than SSH would be.)

This may also work with some commercial "privacy" VPN services, although to my knowledge they typically block client-to-client communications.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need VPN or port-forwarding if you used a cloud storage
solution, such as Dropbox or OneDrive for example
(but there are more).

Many of these cloud storage services have a generous free account, but
also cheap paid programs.
From time to time one can find special offers on the
internet for lifetime subscriptions (I'm actually subscribed to three
such services).